# onclick change parent url ruby on rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Goal: on click open new tab and change url of parent page.

```
  <%= search_form_for @q, url: pages_auto_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.search_field(:name) %>
      <%= f.button :submit, :id => "changeit", :formtarget => "_blank" do %>
         Search
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

application.js file

```
$("#changeit").on("click", function(){
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
});
```

after clicking search button , new tab open but parent page stay same. i need parent page to redirect other url.

Any idea, what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
window.opener.location.href="https://google.com"
```

So you can try it

```
$("#changeit").on("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() { location.href='http://google.com'; }, 0) }
}
```

Comment: So you can try it 
    $("#ID_FORM").on("submit", function(){
        setInterval(function() { location.href='http://google.com'; }, 0) }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You just try this..

```
//As an HTTP redirect (back button will not work )
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");

//like if you click on a link (it will be saved in the session history, 
//so the back button will work as expected)
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Otherwise try this..

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location = 'path-here';">
```